# Beginner Android Development: findViewById issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I get the following error message when running my basic application.
The application consists of a button called button1 and a textView called topLeft.

```
07-01 15:33:02.754: D/AndroidRuntime(2334): Shutting down VM 07-01 15:33:02.754: W/dalvikvm(2334): threadid=1: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300) 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
07-01 15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-01 15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 07-01
15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-01 15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-01
15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 07-01
15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-01
15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-01 15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 07-01
15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825) 07-01
15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28) 07-01
15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 07-01 15:33:02.984:
E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-01 15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
07-01 15:33:02.984: E/AndroidRuntime(2334):     ... 11 more
```

When attempting to use the **findViewById**, this error comes up referring to line 28.

The program looks like the following:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    int a = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
    }


    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView topLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//  button1.setOnClickListener( this );

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }    

}
```

What does this mean? Why is my code having trouble doing something along the lines of referring to the R.java file?

```
R.java does have
    public static final class id {
        public static final int button1=0x7f080001;
        public static final int menu_settings=0x7f080003;
        public static final int textView1=0x7f080000;
        public static final int textView2=0x7f080002;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById` as part of your field definition, at which point the layout isn't inflated (that happens when you call `setContentView`). `findViewById` isn't finding the view, so the reference is being set to `null`.

**Moving your `findViewById` calls inside of `onCreate`, after calling `setContentView` should fix it.**

Comment: Sure. You should "accept" the answer if it fully answers the question. Note that the percentage of accepted answers shows below your name in the profile card on Stack Overflow, and having a higher percentage will likely get you more and better answers.